# How to override cached data in localStorage properly

Tags: javascript, caching, local-storage, browser-cache

I need to cache a list of items that is not going to change very often. I realized that I can cache it in the browser and I asked myself how do I force the stored data to be overridden.
I thought about naming the key as a datestamp and every time that I want to replace it, I'd just change the key to a newer datestamp, e.g `localStorage.setItem("25/01/2021", "['John','Bryan','Mark'..]")`
Is this way practical? What is the customary way to do it?

Comment: You can have a single key, and just overwrite it whenever you need.

Comment: you need to clear or delete old items, lest you run out of quota.